# Heap Sort - max heap

Tags: sorting, max, heap, heapsort

I have a list of numbers in [17,98,89,42,67,54,89,25,38] which is to be inserted in an empty heap from left to right . what will be the resulting heap ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too specific and not useful to other readers.

Comment: I think you can get full information you need in Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort

Comment: homeworkoverflow.com ?

Comment: I know what is heap sort . I just wanted to know is there any special kind of  heap sort where the left child has to be lower than the right child for any given node. My query was related to that . @Thilo

Comment: You did not mention that in the question. Check with your instructor how they want their heap to work, but a general "max heap" just has parent nodes larger than all child nodes (with no special relationship between left and right).

Comment: There is no special kind of binary heap in which the left child has to be less than the right child. If you tried to enforce that rule, your heap would be very expensive to maintain, and you couldn't meet the O(log n) guarantees for the *insert* and *remove-max* operations. For your primary question, take a piece of paper and a pencil and go through the insert operations manually, drawing the tree after each step. It'll take you about 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't the heap sort algorithm (sorts a data set by using heap), building a heap does require some comparison work to ensure it remains a heap (you're wanting a max heap, so all children are less than their parent). The way to build a max heap is to put the newest element in the next available spot (the left-most spot in the tree not filled within the deepest row, or starting a new row from the left-most spot). Once an element is inserted it is swapped with its parent if it's bigger than its parent until it either becomes the root of the tree or finds a parent bigger than itself. This is done until all elements are inserted, and it, in fact, has the max element as the root.

It is important to note that for a min heap, the minimum element is the root, so instead of having all parents bigger than their children, it becomes all children bigger than their parent. In building a min heap, still add new vertices to the same spot, but switch the new child with their parent if the child is less than the parent instead of more.

Two images have been attached with the resulting max & min heaps. Note that 89a corresponds to the first 89 and 89b corresponds to the seconds, for clarification purposes. [Max Heap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42z98.png) [Min Heap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyyrg.png)